# Which method for storing creation date, update, creator ... should I use

Tags: mysql

I am designing a database for a site which will be heavily datadriven with forums and chat and other community features.

My question is this: I have identified certain information I would like to store for at least most of the tables. Creation date, last update, creator and others.

Which is the best way to store these, in a dedicated table or as fields in each respective table?

Why is the better solution better? 
Can the opinion of best solution change if I have 50 tables or 100 tables?
100 000 records vs 4 million?

Are there other aspects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creation date and last update date are best stored as columns in the same table with their respective data.  By doing that, you can use the `TIMESTAMP` data type so they are updated automatically when their respective rows change.

The `NULL` timestamp on the `row_created` column will default to the timestamp when the row is created.  In `row_updated`, the timestamp will be updated automatically every time the row is modified in any way.  You do not need to modify them in application code.

```
CREATE TABLE test.table (
  row_created TIMESTAMP NULL,
  row_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

The creator user isn't as critical to store in the same table, but it doesn't really hurt to do it in the same table or another.  For simplicity I would keep it in the same table.